# Multiple Field with path '...' set 'initialValue'. Can not decide which one to pick, using react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using ant design library and I have the next code, which is a simple dynamic form like here: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-frog-gmkgv?file=/index.js

Bellow is my code:

```js
        <Form.List name="names">
          {(fields, { add }) => {
            return (
              <div>
                {fields.map(field => (
                  <Space
                    key={field.key}
                  >
                    <div>
                      <Form.Item
                        {...field}
                        name={[field.name, 'title']}
                        fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, 'title']}
                        rules={[
                          {
                            required: true,
                            message: 'Please input title!',
                          },
                        ]}
                      >
                        <Input placeholder="title" />
                      </Form.Item>
                      <div className="class_9">
                        <Form.Item
                          {...field}
                          name="data1"
                          key={`data1{field.name}`}
                          fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, 'data1']}
                          initialValue={moment().add(110, 'days')}
                          rules={[
                            {
                              required: true,
                              message: 'Missing',
                            },
                          ]}
                        >
                          <DatePicker
                            showToday={false}
                            bordered
                            suffixIcon={false}
                            onChange={change}
                          />
                        </Form.Item>
                          <Form.Item
                            {...field}
                            name="time2"
                            fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, 'time2']}
                            key={`time2{field.name}`}
                            initialValue={moment('02:00', 'HH mm')}
                            rules={[
                              {
                                required: false,
                                message: 'Missing',
                              },
                            ]}
                          >
                            <TimePicker
                              allowClear={false}
                              format="HH:mm"
                              suffixIcon={false}
                            />
                          </Form.Item>
                          <Form.Item
                            {...field}
                            name="time3"
                            fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, 'time3']}
                            key={`time3{field.name}`}
                            initialValue={moment('15:30', 'HH mm')}
                            rules={[
                              {
                                required: false,
                                message: 'Missing',
                              },
                            ]}
                          >
                            <TimePicker
                              allowClear={false}
                              format="HH:mm"
                              style={{ paddingLeft: '5px' }}
                              suffixIcon={false}
                              
                            />
                          </Form.Item>
                         
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <Form.Item className="submit">
                        <Button  htmlType="submit">
                          submit
                        </Button>
                      </Form.Item>
                    </div>
                  </Space>
                ))}

                <Form.Item>
                  <Button
                    type="dashed"
                    onClick={() => {
                      add();
                    }}
                    block
                  >
                    Add field
                  </Button>
                </Form.Item>
              </div>
            );
          }}
        </Form.List>
```

When i click on `add field` button, i get:

```css
Multiple Field with path 'names.data1' set 'initialValue'. Can not decide which one to pick
```

```css
Multiple Field with path 'names.time2' set 'initialValue'. Can not decide which one to pick
```

```css
Multiple Field with path 'names.time3' set 'initialValue'. Can not decide which one to pick
```

Question: Why these warnings appears?

Comment: The code sandbox is not reproducing the error.

Comment: @RohanAgarwal, i added the sanbox. Could you help?

Comment: @RohanAgarwal, the code is working on your side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your static

```
              <Form.Item
                {...field}
                name="time1"
```

to dynamic `name` property

```
              <Form.Item
                {...field}
                name={[field.name, "time1"]}
```

Comment: could you please help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69428679/send-a-request-inside-a-rendered-list-of-elements-in-reactjs