# Pass a default prop inside function component in react js

Tags: reactjs

I created a react component which takes 2 props: `func1`, `func2`.

```
const Component = ({ func1, func2 }) => {
  return (
          <Button
            onClick={() => {
              func1();
              func2();
            }}
            
          >
            Click
          </Button>
  );
};
```

The above component is reusable. I have a situation where I pass both functions (func1, func2) as props in this component:

```
<Component func1={functionA} func2={functionC}/>
```

I also have situations where I don't pass both props:

```
<Component func1={functionA}/>
```

In the last case, how to set the `func2` as alternative prop?

Comment: what do you mean by "alternative" prop?

Comment: How about calling `funct1` and `funct2` on conditional basis? `funct1 && funct1()`

Comment: @Apostolos, i mean, when i will use `<Component/>` like in the last case i don't want to get the error, that i forgot to pass `func2`. I need to change something in the Component, and to be prepared that both props could be use not as required.

Comment: @AskMen, so I guess Neeko's answer fits your needs. I would make a small change though. instead of null i would say `func2 = () => return false`

Comment: @Apostolos, could you take a look, please, and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62931413/multiple-field-with-path-set-initialvalue-can-not-decide-which-one-to-p   , it will be very helpful

Comment: @AskMen check my answer to the other question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set a default parameter when you declare your component:

```
const Component = ({ func1, func2 = null }) => {
  return (
          <Button
            onClick={() => {
              func1();
              if (func2 && typeof func2 === "function") {
                func2();
              }
            }}
            
          >
            Click
          </Button>
  );
};
```

Your `func2` will now be equal to `null` (or whatever value you want to assign) when no prop is provided.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to how to do it:

```
const ParentFunc2 = () => {
  console.log("ParentFun2");
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TestComponent func2={ParentFunc2} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

TestComponent:

```
import React from "react";

const func1Default = () => {
  console.log("func1");
};

const func2Default = () => {
  console.log("func2");
};

export default function TestComponent({
  func1 = func1Default,
  func2 = func2Default
}) {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        func1();
        func2();
      }}
    >
      Click{" "}
    </button>
  );
}
```

Live example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-rgb-xidfe?file=/src/App.js